# How to set array key same as value

Tags: php

I have a question that seems obvious but I can't reproduce it yet.
Well, let's say I have an array:

```
$array = ('apple', 'orange', 'banana');
```

So I would actually like to have the same array but with the same keys as the values, something like this:

```
array(
    'apple' => 'apple',
    'orange' => 'orange',
    'banana' => 'banana'
);
```

How would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array('first','second','third');

$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    $newArray[$value] = $value;
}
```

Or just initialize the array as you wanted to:

```
$array = array(
    'first' => 'first',
    'second' => 'second'
);
```

Comment: Great! thanks you very much @Ommy Wommy! But I wonder if it will work if you have an array like $array = ( 0 => 'apple', 1 => 'orange', 2 => 'banana');

Comment: it will work since the for loop is iterating the values, key is irrelevant at that point.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and combine the array with itself. But beware that *Illegal values for key will be converted to string.* This means you also might lose duplicates after the string conversion. Example:

```
$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana',[], 'Array');
$array = array_combine($array,$array);
var_dump($array);
```

[3v4l link without duplicates](https://3v4l.org/I37j6), [3v4l link with duplicate after string conversion](https://3v4l.org/71eYs)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
$array['apple'] = 'apple';
$array['orange'] = 'orange';
```